# Average Rate of Change f(x) involving sin

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

[image]

Can anyone check and tell me if 34/19 is correct - that's what I got it. If not can someone explain how to solve this. Thanks! :)

Comment: It is correct.${}{}$

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: oh dang.... did not realise that. HAHA. i was planning to use this space for entire book work of clarifications. Sigh, I'll have to work on the new skills i've learned today :P  - i think I'll only post questions that i have completely no idea to solve, unlike the above. Thanks :) !! That helped!

Comment: Is there any other way you can post questions with the limit running :/ ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I will solve it

Average rate of change between $a$ and $b$ is 
$$
\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$$

I don't have a calculator handy but you can check the answer

Comment: I get 34/19 also. Found my calculator!

Comment: WOOHOO! :P thanks alot. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

The average rate of change is represented as
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
where $a=1/4, b=5.$

Comment: yup thats what i did. thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome!